# Stuck with Piggybak install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I have followed the base application and installation docs.  I have Devise,Rails_Admin, and Cancan installed and bundled.  I think I followed those install docs too.  I have the admin set up and I can add users.  But when I do the piggybak install I get an error.  I have pulled my repo and done this three times but still cant't get past here.  Any help from anyone who has installed piggybak successfully.

> $ piggybak install
>
> add reference to devise in GEMFILE
>
> insert  GEMFILE

/home/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thor-0.16.0/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:99:in `binread': No such file or directory - /home/jason/work/kpipe/GEMFILE (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: Ok I made progress. When I put gem piggybak in the gemfile and bundled I got v0.6.2.This is the direction from the doc.  I tried a gem install piggybak.  However doing a gem install piggybak gave me v0.6.23.  I then did the piggybak install per the docs and it worked. Dependency issues? Go figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a temporary link in your home project to point to your Gemfile

```
ln -s Gemfile GEMFILE
```

Then run the piggybak install.

It suppose it is an error in piggybak, maybe they develope it on windows machine where the case doesn't matter.

Comment: I gave it another try recently and you nailed it.  Thanks Ivailo.